# yii2 правила для поддоменов

Tags: php, yii2

Здравствуйте. Фреймворк YII2. Есть frontend часть с админкой, которая реализованная модулем. Url для доступа к админ части - `http://site.dev/admin/<controller>/<action>`. Задача вынести модуль админки на поддомен.

В urlManager прописал такое правило
`getenv('ADMIN_DOMAIN').'<controller>/<action>' => 'admin/<controller>/<action>'`,
где в `getenv('ADMIN_DOMAIN')` нужный адрес админки. Работает правильно, роуты доступны из поддомена - admin.site/main/index .

Но проблема в том, что админка доступна также и по изначальному url - `http://site.dev/admin/<controller>/<action>`, который уже в свою очередь редиректит на поддомен. 
Скажите как запретить доступ по старому url ? Чтобы была 404 ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать правило типа `'admin/<controller>/<action>' => 'main/site/error'`, где `'main/site/error'` это путь до страницы 404. Или просто задать путь на несуществующую страницу, должно по идее автоматом выдавать 404.